# Can I redirect an HTML link on our webpage to another server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, redirect, redirection

We have a website that we host. In the sites header, we have links to sections of our site. eg.

`[Logo] [Buy] [Sell] [Pew Pew]`

and the current links are

```
Logo: / (root of the site)
Buy: /buy/
Sell: /sell/
Pew Pew: /pew-pew/
```

Now, our team want to get another company to do the 'buy' section. So instead of our code showing that content, another company (and another server) will do it.

So we need to make sure that when a user clicks our the [buy] link, it goes to their server with the SAME url

eg.

our server handles -

```
http://www.foo.com
http://www.foo.com/selling
http://www.foo.com/pew-pew
```

and their server handles

```
http://www.foo.com/buying
```

Is this possible?

Our server is IIS7.5 on Windows 2008 r2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, in theory, proxy requests for a subset of the URL space -- when your webserver receives the request for, say, `/buying/foo/bar`, it makes a request to `http://outsourced.example.com/foo.com/buying/foo/bar`, and then sends the results it gets for that request to your client.

I say "in theory", because it's really not such a hot idea -- it increases latency to your users, and becomes a bit of a management pain (debugging and configuration complexity).  Users really don't give a flying fig if their URLs are `buy.foo.com` for a given subset of the site, and you can even do interesting cookie things to make the session experience seamless.

I don't have any specific notes on how to do proxying in IIS, because I Don't Do Windows.  I know that simple URL rewriting was a third-party add-on until very recently, so it wouldn't surprise me if proxying is still an add-on.  A separate question on "IIS proxying" might garner some useful answers from those in the know.

Comment: So in general (regardless of the platform) I can't 301 or direct a user to another IP address while keeping the same domainname? Your suggesting that I retrieve the data from the -other- server, and then feed that answer back to the user (man in the middle proxy)?

Comment: Of course you can't.  You can't redirect to a different URL while keeping the same URL, it's non-sensical.

Comment: @Pure **IF** you still want to go this route you will need URL Rewrite module and [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) module installed. Docs: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/740/application-request-routing-module/